# Django Admin site - display issue

Tags: django, admin

I a newbie to django and am following the docs in [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html) to setup admin functionanlity .  After doing the same I get the following result/dsiplay.

[image]

whereas in the book , the display is quite dofferent, something like the below :

[image]

PS: I understand the the second pic is in MAC whereas I'm doing my stuff on windows. BUt i am confused as to why the CSS and other links not appearing on my admin site?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks theguywhoanswered for the answer(which I presume he has deleted). It resolved my issue. The cause was two fold and needed the following modifications.

Changes required

In settings.py add

```
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).ancestor(2)
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static_media/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In urls.py add

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
url(r'static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

Also create a admin.py file under books directory whose contents should be :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

also run `python manage.py collectstatic` from mysite directory

After doing all this restart the server. Your page should look like below [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` in settings.py is uncommented, this it was my trouble.